# Revert changes in python try exception block before raising

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, code-duplication

I need to update one attribute of an object for a single validation. I need to revert that in any case and before the Validation raises an error.
I'm currently confused if this is actually the most beautiful way to revert something before the Exception raises because then I have to duplicate the revert code.
`finally` does not work here as it is executed after the raise statement.

```py
amount = instance.amount
instance.amount = 0
try:
    validate_instance(instance)
except Exception:
    instance.amount = amount
    raise
else:
    instance.amount = amount
```

Comment: In  your code block, do you mean to always revert it back to the old value `amount` whether there was an exception or none? As it is present in both `except` and `else`.

Comment: What do you mean by: `executed after the raise statement`? In my experiment with `try:except:finally:` the `finally` executes before the `raise` makes control leave the current function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally block should be fine, as shown below:

```
amount = 15

def throw_me_an_error():
    try:
        amount = 20
        print("I've set the amount to 20.")
        test = 'hey' + 1
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception thrown')
        raise e
    else:
        print('Else part')
    finally:
        amount = 15
        print('I reverted the amount to 15.')
        print('Finally!')
        
try:
    throw_me_an_error()
except Exception:
    print('An exception was thrown')
    
print(f'The amount is now {amount}')
```

results in

```
I've set the amount to 20.
Exception thrown
I reverted the amount to 15.
Finally!
An exception was thrown
The amount is now 15
```

Comment: finally works fine indeed, I thought it would have worked differently

Comment: The part within "finally" is executed before the error is thrown to the parent code who called your functionality (updated my answer which makes it more visible).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the other answers, finally works indeed fine:

```py
>>> try:
...     try:
...         print(1)
...         x += 1
...     except Exception:
...         raise
...     finally:
...         print(2)
... except Exception:
...     print(3)
... 
1
2
3
```